# I cant find the questions I asked in Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area51

I asked a question in Area 51 when this site was in its infancy. It was a good question about English marriage and the answers may be useful to others here.  Keeping that aside I thought this question would be retained in the Beta but its not attributed to my account.

I went back into area 51 to find it as I am researching that subject again and couldn’t find it.  What happened to the questions in Area 51, should they be migrated here?

Comment: I asked this last October Stephen (http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1148/108). It's a shame. There should have been some automated help to get such questions migrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area 51 is a special site where new Stack Exchange sites are proposed. In the definition phase, example questions are proposed and voted on to get a rough idea of what the site will be about when it gets to beta. These example questions stay on Area 51 and are purely for example. They are not answered there and are not migrated to the site when it reaches the beta phase. The questions are still accessible [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502?phase=definition) (unless they've been deleted), but are locked because there purpose as example questions has been fulfilled.

I've taken a look at your Area 51 account and I don't see any questions proposed by you. If you *did* propose a question, the only reason that it doesn't appear that I can think of is that it has been deleted.

If your question was deleted, the deletion is permanent and only users with enough rep and the community team (Stack Exchange employees) will be able to see it.

On second thought, if you asked the question with an unregistered account, it would not be linked to your registered account in any way. Only mods can merge the accounts back together.

Example questions are sometimes re-asked as a real question in the beta phase, but this doesn't necessarily guarantee that they are on-topic (even if they were un-closed or even up-voted on Area 51).

Comment: That explains it.  Thanks

Comment: With humble apologies, I just discovered I posted the genealogy question to the History Stack just before Area 51 was set up.  http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/why-did-some-people-need-to-pay-a-bond-in-the-1700s-in-order-to-get-married/3112#3112

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt to try to get that question migrated to Genealogy and Family History.

Comment: @lkessler The question may be too old to migrate, even if it didn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - I don't think questions are ever too old to migrate. There were a whole bunch of questions that were years old that migrated from StackOverflow to Programming when Programming was created.

Comment: @lkessler, Nothing older than 60 days can be migrated now.